# Развертывание приложения на С# с базой данный для SQL Express?

Tags: c#, sql, развертывание

Есть консольное приложение на C#. Оно подключено к базе данных SQL Express (строка подключения: "Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=Company;Trusted_Connection=True").

С помощью ClickOnce создаю установочный файл (туда включаю установочные файлы DotNet Sdk и SQL Express) и прилагаю резервную копию базы данных.

Как после развертывания, автоматически, в SQL Express вставить базу данных?

Я написал скрипт восстановления базы данных:

```
string commandRestore = "sqlcmd -E -S .\\SQLEXPRESS -Q\"RESTORE DATABASE Company FROM DISK='C:\\Data\\CompanyBackup.bak'\"";

Process cmdProcess = new Process();

cmdProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
cmdProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c " + commandRestore;
cmdProcess.Start();
```

Как правильно реализовать данный скрипт при установке программы, либо при первом запуске программы? Или все это делается по другому?

P.S. Я знаю, что есть LocalDB, SQLite, но меня интересует как правильно это сделать с SQL Express.

Comment: ну можно миграции написать или sql файлик для создания БД подготовить.

Comment: лично у меня 2 проги, одна с SQL Compact работает, другая с MySQL/MariaDB и обе сами создадут БД и нужные миграции запустят при подключении к базе данных. Использовал EF + Code First

Comment: У меня уже есть база данных. "Ручным" способом я могу ее установить у клиента, а как сделать автоматически?

Comment: Экспорт ее в sql и накатывать этот скрипт при запуске?